Hartshorne II, Lemma 4.4 Applying to Local Rings
Hartshorne's Lemma 4.4 states: if $R$ is a valuation ring of a field $K$, giving a morphism of $\textrm{Spec} R$ to a scheme $X$ is equivalent to giving two points $x_0,x_1$ in $X$ with $x_0$ a specialization of $x_1$ and an inclusion of fields $k(x_1)\subset K$, such that $R$ dominates the local ring $O$ of $x_0$ on the subscheme $Z=\bar{\{x_1\}}$ of $X$ with its induced subscheme structure.
My question is: why does the proof not apply to the case where $R$ is simply a local ring?

It never uses the fact $R$ is a valuation ring. As far as I can tell, the valuative criterion for separatedness would work if we only spoke of local domains. You said $R$ a local ring - that's not good enough - local domain is what we want. However, I think the valuative criterion for properness is only correct when tested against valuation rings.

I didn't like Hartshorne's proof. Here are  some related questions about alternative proofs and so on
